# Laravel 5: How to saveMany() based on value

Tags: php, laravel

I need a little help with the following situation.

I am willing to `saveMany` based on the input value. Let me give code example.

I was experimenting with the following.

```
       $data = [
      'id' => 1,
      'name' => 'example',
      'number_of_slots' => 5,
      'material' => 'Colo',
      'equipment_status_code_id' => 1,
    ];

    $platecontainer = PlateContainer::create($data);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $platecontainer->containerSlots()->saveMany([
          new ContainerSlot([
            'plate_container_id' => $data['id'],
            'slot' =>  $data['number_of_slots'],
            'occuiped' => false,
            ])
        ]);
    }
```

until `$platecontainer` everything works just great. What I want is when a `PlateContainer` is created using the `data` array, I want to create slots as well, but this one is based on `number_of_slots`

So for instance `number_of_slots` in the example is `5` so I want to save `5` records in (**descending** order) in the `ContainerSlot` table

so the containerslots table will end up looking something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The save many method accepts an array of models, so just use a `for` loop for the `$plateContainer`'s `number_of_slots`

```
$plateContainer = PlateContainer::create($data);

$containers = [];

// Need to add one to our number of slots because
// the $i count starts at one instead of zero.
$slots = $plateContainer->number_of_slots + 1;

for($i = 1; $i < $slots; $i++) {
    $containers[] =  new ContainerSlot([
        'plate_container_id' => $plateContainer->getKey(),
        'slot' =>  $i,
        'occuiped' => false,
    ]);
}

$plateContainer->containerSlots()->saveMany($containers);
```

Comment: does assigning id to `palate_container_id` is necessary?it would be assigned automatically when using `saveMany()`

Comment: @alex You're right, but I'm also not aware of his model setup. For explanation purposes I've left it there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use createMany (array of arrays of attributes) instead of saveMany (array of models new or existing). Useful for API calls.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if you want to insert data based on value, you can prepare your array and let the model insert in bulk.

```
$itemRebates = array_map(function ($rebateId) use ($payoutItem) {
    return [
        'rebate_id' => $rebateId,
        'payout_item_id' => $payoutItem->id
    ];
}, $rebateIds);

PayoutItemRebate::insert($itemRebates);
```

This way you don't need to wrap your data in multiple model instances.

### Additional details

I tried to use the `insert` method from `$payoutItem->historyRebates()` but it didn't take the `payout_item_id` from the relationship. So it's better to use the model itself.

My first attempt was to use `saveMany`, but even preparing the data, it doesn't work with arrays, only with model instances. I wanted to avoid that.